# ColdFusion Builder 2 and ColdBox on a Remote Server

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder, coldbox

I have a remote Ubuntu server, but I work on a Windows computer.

My idea was to work with [ColdBox](http://www.coldbox.org), but I cannot perform the installation on the remote server, because it does not match the installation directory with the webroot.

Is the use of ColdBox as such possible, or have I made ​​a mistake?